# Forwarding request when serving from NGINX cache - Is this possible?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, cache, proxypass

I have enabled caching with Nginx. I followed the [official docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/) and it works fine. What happens is, when the request comes in for the first time, it is proxy passed to a server. The response is cached.

From there on, all requests are served from the Nginx cache until it expires. But I want an additional thing.

Here is what I want:

1. When the request is served from the cache, I want to make an API request to my server so that I do not loose on the number of hits (counter)

How can I do this?

I had tried the `mirror` command, but it does not get called when the page is served from cache. It only gets called when the cache expires. Here is the config snapshot that I tried. Is this even possible? Any other way to do this?

[image]

**EDIT**
Cache directive as highlighted in the second screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Do you even get cache hits? There are no nginx caching directives here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Updated my screenshot. `proxy_cache`  directives are there.

Comment: Use Nginx access log to count your number of hits.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I want to call a custom API when the cache hit takes place. Is this possible?

Comment: Please add configuration information as text, not as screenshots. Screenshots are difficult to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible. The `mirror` directive is processed as a subrequest to the original request, so if nginx does not process the original request, the mirror request will also not be processed.

As a workaround, you can add a second custom `access_log` directive, which uses a custom `log_format`. Your program can then read this log to determine when a cache hit occurred and to which URL. In fact, it could just use that log to count all hits, cached or not.

Comment: Could you please share a small example

Comment: I got it. Does this file ever get purged by Nginx?

Comment: @SuhailGupta No, you have to rotate logs yourself, e.g. with logrotate.

Comment: Is there a service that streams nginx logs? I want to continuously read logs into my application and put those into database.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Something like logstash?